# Creating BorderRadius within a Scaffold in BottomSheet and minChildSize issue

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

**Code B** below is pop up from clicking `showModalBottomSheet`. It works fine as it is. But I am trying to fix 2 issues with this code.

*Issue 1:* The `maxChildSize` and `minChildSize` doesn't seem to be working. How can this be fixed?

*Issue 2:* Where can I input **Code A** into **Code B** to curve the edges of the `BottomSheet`? It works fine on my other BottomSheet with `Containers` but since this `BottomSheet` has a Scaffold with an `AppBar`, I am not sure how to curve it.

**Code A:**

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                    )),
```

**Code B:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.79,
      maxChildSize: 0.79,
      minChildSize: 0.3,
      builder: (_, controller) =>
          Container(
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  title: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 10),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Text(),
                  ),
                  elevation: 0,
                  toolbarHeight: 60,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  actions: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                      child: IconButton(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                body: Column(
                    children: [
                Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 5, 30, 10),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: TextField(),
                decoration: InputDecoration()),
          ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: assetList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {},
      ),
    ),
    ],
  ),)
  ,
  );
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **second** issue can fix by adding `decoration` and `clipBehavior` to your parent container like this:

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(// <--- add this
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,// <--- add this
            child: Scaffold(
              ...
            )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated eamirho3ein! That fixes issue 2.